# laravel count records based on each single date

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

In my database I have records something like

```
**my_table_name**

id      date_column               status
1       2020-07-21 00:29:05       done
2       2020-07-21 21:29:05       done
3       2020-07-21 21:35:05       failed
4       2020-07-22 10:29:05       done
5       2020-07-22 10:35:05       done
6       2020-07-22 10:37:05       failed
7       2020-07-22 10:39:05       failed
8       2020-07-22 10:40:05       done
```

And using laravel query I want result like

```
array(
    [0]=>array(
        'date'=>'2020-07-21',
        'failed'=>1
        'done'=>2
     ),
   [0]=>array(
        'date'=>'2020-07-22',
        'failed'=>2
        'done'=>3
     )
)
```

How can I do this?

I have tried

```
$record=DB::table('my_table_name')
                    ->select(
                            DB::raw("DATE_FORMAT(date_column, 'Y-m-d') as date"),
                            DB::raw("SUM(status= 'failed') as failed"),
                            DB::raw("SUM(status= 'done') as done"),
                            )
                    ->where('date_column','>=','2020-07-21 00:00:00')
                    ->where('date_column','<=','2020-07-22 23:59:59')
                    ->groupBy(DB::raw("DATE_FORMAT(date_column, 'Y-m-d')"))
                    ->get();
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems to be fine but using date format of 'Y-m-d' instead of '%Y-%m-%d' which is wrong.

In order to solve your issue, use below query:

```
DB::table('my_table_name')::select(
            DB::raw("DATE_FORMAT(date_column, '%Y-%m-%d') as date"),
            DB::raw("SUM(name= 'failed') as failed"),
            DB::raw("SUM(name= 'done') as done"),
            )
            ->whereDate('date_column','>=','2020-07-21')
            ->whereDate('date_column','<=','2020-07-22')
            ->groupBy(DB::raw("DATE_FORMAT(date_column, '%Y-%m-%d')"))
            ->get();
```

Comment: well it is working now but is there any way that it must return count for dates in between range currently it is not returning any record for that date if there is no record

Comment: try to use whereDate instead where